# Click event for button on 2nd page of multi-page jquerymobile document does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events, jquery-click-event

My simple mobile app has 3 pages all demarcated with divs/ `data-role="page"` and within the same document (.html). The pages load up perfectly but if I navigate to the 2nd page, a very simple click event on a button does not work.

In the  I have the following within script tags:

```
$('#igetdetails').click(function () {
    alert("hello");
})
```

`igetdetails` being the id of the button. The alert never pops up.

When I place this code within the pageinit event of that page however, it pops up immediately the page is loaded.

This tells me there must be something very simple I'm missing out but after 8 hours of strain and pain I'm reaching out for help.

Here's the full head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="my.js">
    </script>
    <script>
  //  Invoice = new Object();
   $( '#page1' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
        //alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );


       // Ajax Called When Page is Load/Ready (Load Customers)
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'list_customers.php',
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,    
            success: populateCustomers
        }); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'list_salesmen.php',
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,    
            success: populateSalesmen
        }); 

        $("#iinv_customer").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
            Invoice.CustomerID = $('#iinv_customer').val();                
        });
        $("#iinv_salesman").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
            Invoice.SalesmanID = $('#iinv_salesman').val();                
        });
        $("#iinv_date").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
            Invoice.Date = $('#iinv_date').val();                
        });
        $("#iinv_no").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
            Invoice.invno = $('#iinv_no').val();                
        });
        $("#iinv_add").bind( "click", function(event, ui) {

            $('#iinv_customer').selectmenu('disable');
            $('#iinv_salesman').selectmenu('disable');
            $('#iinv_no').textinput('disable');
            $('#iinv_date').textinput('disable');                

            $.mobile.changePage("#page4");
        });
        $("#iinv_cancel").bind( "click", function(event, ui) {

            $('#iinv_customer').selectmenu('disable');
            $('#iinv_salesman').selectmenu('disable');
            $('#iinv_no').textinput('disable');
            $('#iinv_date').textinput('disable');                

            //$('#page1').reset();
            location.reload();
        });

    });

     $( '#page4' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
        //alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );

        //$('#iSelectedCustomer').html($('#iinv_customer').val());
        $('#iSelectedCustomer').html($("#iinv_customer option[value='" + $('#iinv_customer').val() +"']").text());
       // document.getElementById("iSelectedCustomer").innerHTML = $('#iSelectedCustomer').html();
            //var element = document.getElementById('iSelectedCustomer');
            //alert(element.value);
            //element.value = $('#iinv_customer').value;
            //alert(element.value);
    //    var selected = $(#iinv_customer).val;

     //   $('#iSelectedCustomer').val(selected);

       jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'list_products.php',
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,    
            success: populateProducts
        }); 

     });

     $('#igetdetails').click(function () 
     {    
         alert("hello");
     //$("#ili_prod").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
     //var data = { prod: 12};
     var data = { prod: $("#ili_prod").val()};
     // prodid = $(this).attr('value');

     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'get_products_details.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data:data,
        async: false,    
        success: populateProductsDetails

     });
     alert($("#ili_prod").val());
     alert("hello");
     });



    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Sounds like the `#igetdetails` element is not available when you attempt to bind to it. Where are you placing your event binding code?

Comment: @Kiran `.click(...)` is just a shortcut for `.on("click", ...)`. When you call the former the latter is actually run.

Comment: @Kiran: yes, I've fiddled with various formats. That doesn't work too.

Comment: @Jasper: the binding code is within <header></header>. Following this header section, the document has page1, page2 and page3 data-role sections. How else do I place this to ensure availability before execution? I tried placing at the very bottom, before </body> but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Here is another thing you can look: Look at inspector and see where the ID is set. jQuerymobile adds additional markup to your html. Moreover, if there are any other errors in your JS, the event may not fire at all.

Comment: @user1729972 I recommend pasting your code into your question. Truncate it if it's long but keep something in your code that shows where on the document it is placed and make sure to keep all code that is relevant to your question intact.

Comment: @Jasper: I've pasted the full header section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the JS code before the DOM element exists. Since you are using a multi-page template you can just place the code in your question inside a `document.ready` event handler (**be aware that when using single-page-templates this is not a good idea, you should instead use delegated page events**).

Just wrap your code like this:

```
$(function () {
    ...

    $('#igetdetails').click(function () {

    ...
});
```

Comment: Is there an online resource you can point me to that really expounds the sequence of events/ DOM element creation in Javascript? I've run into another (likely obvious) issue and need to do more homework.

Comment: @user1729972 A good explanation of the jQuery `document.ready` event can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the preferred way to do this now is with

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click', '#igetdetails', function(event) {
    alert('hello')
});​
```

This will bind the event for the document and listen for future matching selectors to bind to.

Comment: `.click()` is actually a shortcut, so depending on the version of jQuery you're using you will automatically be using `.bind()` or `.on()`. A benefit of using `.click()` versus `.on("click")`. Also delegated event handlers are not necessary for a jQuery Mobile page where all the pseudo-pages exist on the same document. Delegated event handlers are key for pages loaded via AJAX though.